# Screenshot of multiple HTML pages using PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, screenshot

So as everyone has mentioned in [this github issue](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10619), the viewport size function in phantomJS doesn't behave as a lot of people expected.

I am trying to take screenshots of a web app for an iPad. The site has a `position:fixed;` footer and header. When I take a screenshot I only want to be able to see what would be viewable on the screen when you first load the page, so i've used the following code to clip the page to the size I want.

```
page.clipRect = { top: 0, left: 0, width: 1024, height: 768 };
```

Because the site has a `position: fixed;` header and footer when I do this and take a screenshot, the footer is missing when the content on the page forces a scroll. (Its right at the bottom of the page)

[image]

In the replies, one solution would be to load the page you would like to take a screenshot of into an object with the height and width you of your preference, and then take a screenshot of the object instead.

All the code snippets with this implemented, assume you have a single URL that you would like to take a screenshot of. I would like to take screenshots of multiple html files. I am not fluent in Javascript at all and I'm really struggling to merge these solutions into my code.

---

[This solution](https://github.com/jbeuckm/Splasher) takes a single webpage and converts it into multiple images of differnet sizes using a json file.

While [this solution](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10619#issuecomment-37850554) is more along the lines that i'm looking for but again, just a single web page. Please note that iframe doesn't work and the iframe code would need to be replaced with an object with a data attribute with a value of the html page to be loaded.

And a [final solution](https://gist.github.com/DEfusion/4cc10e23f9ed4d38244f), which is more complete than the others, but again is just a single URL

---

I have been using the following code in the past, and its worked perfectly with web apps built to specific dimensions, but this one has been built slightly differently which is why the screenshots are being a nightmare.

```
var system = require('system');
var dest = system.args[1];
var files = system.args[2].split(',');

function takeScreenshot(destName, index) {
    var page = require('webpage').create();

    // Open the target HTML file
    page.open(dest+'/'+destName+'/'+destName+'.html', function(status) {

        // Only capture 1024x768 area 
        page.clipRect = { top: 0, left: 0, width: 1024, height: 768 };

        // Save as PNG
        page.render(dest+'/'+destName+'/'+destName+'-full.png');

        // Send output to be caught by progress bar
        console.log('OK');

        // If the lop has finished exit, otherwise clean memory
        if(files.length == 0) {
        phantom.exit();
        } else {
            page.close();
            takeScreenshot(files.shift());
        }
    });

}

takeScreenshot(files.shift());
```

dest variable is the destination of the screenshots.

files is an array of files that I would like to take a screenshot of.

Answer (score 0):

It should be easy to combine the [final solution](https://gist.github.com/DEfusion/4cc10e23f9ed4d38244f) with your existing code. The idea is to move the actual code into a function and call the function with the new URL after the previous one finished. When you look into the "final solution", the spots where we are finished with the current page are denoted with `phantom.exit();`. From there you can trigger further screenshots.

Here is the complete script, modified from the version of DEfusion:

```
var args = require('system').args,
    resourceWait  = 300,
    maxRenderWait = 10000,
    mode          = args[3] || 'iframe',
    dest          = args[1],
    files         = args[2].split(','),
    page          = require('webpage').create(),
    count         = 0,
    forcedRenderTimeout,
    renderTimeout;

page.viewportSize = { width: 1024, height : 768 };

function doRender() {
    page.render(filename);
    next();
}

page.onResourceRequested = function (req) {
    count += 1;
    clearTimeout(renderTimeout);
};

page.onResourceReceived = function (res) {
    if (!res.stage || res.stage === 'end') {
        count -= 1;
        if (count === 0) {
            clearTimeout(forcedRenderTimeout);
            renderTimeout = setTimeout(doRender, resourceWait);
        }
    }
};

page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg) {
    console.log("from page: " + msg);
};

function evaluateJsWithArgs(func) {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    var fn = "function() { return (" + func.toString() + ").apply(this, " + JSON.stringify(args) + "); }";
    return page.evaluate(fn);
};

function next(error){
    if (!error) {
        if (files.length == 0){
            phantom.exit();
        } else {
            takeScreenshot(files.shift());
        }
    }
}

function takeScreenshot(file){
    var url = dest+'/'+file+'/'+file+'.html';
    filename = dest+'/'+file+'/'+file+'-full.png';
    if(mode == 'iframe') {
        // use iFrame
        page.open('about:blank', function (status) {
            if (status !== "success") {
                console.log('Unable to load url');
                next(true);
            } else {
                page.includeJs(
                    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js",
                    function() {
                        evaluateJsWithArgs(
                            function(url, w, h) {
                                $('body')
                                    .css({margin: 0, padding: 0})
                                    .append('<object data="' + url + '" width="'+ w + '" height="' + h + '" id="screen-frame" />');
                                $('#screen-frame')
                                    .width(w)
                                    .height(h);
                            },
                            url,
                            page.viewportSize.width,
                            page.viewportSize.height
                        );
                    }
                );

                forcedRenderTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
                    doRender();
                }, maxRenderWait);
            }
        });
    } else {
        // resize body
        page.open(url, function(status) {
            if (status !== "success") {
                console.log('Unable to load url');
                next(true);
            } else {
                page.includeJs(
                    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js",
                    function() {
                        evaluateJsWithArgs(
                            function(w,h) {
                               $('body, html').css({
                                    width: w + 'px',
                                    height: h + 'px',
                                    overflow: 'hidden'
                               });
                            },
                            page.viewportSize.width,
                            page.viewportSize.height
                        );

                        forcedRenderTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
                            doRender();
                        }, maxRenderWait);
                    }
                );
            }
        });
    }
}

takeScreenshot(files.shift());
```

Comment: ah I was really hoping this would work. But unfortunately its not :(. As I'm running this as part of a grunt task, its really tricky to debug as console logs get output. Can you recommend any methods of running this outside of grunt please? Thank you so much.

Comment: What do you mean, it doesn't work. That phrase carries absolutely no information. Please be more specific. I noticed that the iframe variant doesn't work for local files. I have no experience with grunt so I can't help you there.

Comment: Sorry, I knew it was a bad response, but because I can't log anything out as its running behind grunt I didn't know what else to say. So I've taken this script out of grunt to try and run it straight from the terminal using phantomjs screenshot.js. I've replaced all the system arguments with what values grunt would pass to the screenshot.js file. When I run this command I get a CoreText performance note appearing in the console. I the destination directory image files are being created but they do not contain any screenshot, just a completely blank image. I'll keep trying to debug this.

Comment: I've created a test html page just to make sure that the object actually makes the page appear as expected. It does. I've logged out the variables for URL, filename, all seem ok. Still stumped

Comment: I've got a feeling that this might have something to do with the locations of the pages in reference to the file location. I am executing this screenshot script in the following file location. root/tools/screenshot.js. The pages that I am taking screenshots in are in root/dist/files.html. Do you know if the file locations are references from where I run the script (the root for example) or where the script lives (root/tools/screenshot.js)